# Can't import references in forms designer

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, listview

I'm trying to make ObjectListView (http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net) library to work in my project. I added the ObjectListView project to my solution, and I've built it without errors. Now after trying to add a DataListView custom control to my form, I'm getting errors, and when I'm trying to import references in the Form1.Designer.cs file as VS/Resharper suggests nothing happens.

The error is, `Import 'BrightIdeasSoftware.DataListView' and other references?`:

[image]

I click many times to add the references on these lines, and still no effect:

```
private DataListView dataListView1;
private OLVColumn olvColumn1;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting ?

Comment: You can add using of custom components namespace to Form1.cs file (not in Form1.Designer.c). Also you need to add 'objectlistview' project to references.

Comment: @KobyDouek - http://imgur.com/a/jDwjN . But I think they will be gone, once I beat the references problem that I can't add

Comment: @JohnG - the project is ObjectListView, and I'm adding it's component: DataListView. 
@IvanKishchenko - but the `private DataListView dataListView1; private OLVColumn olvColumn1;` were added automatically, should I really put them somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is that you can't reference it by clicking the dialog, then reference it by yourself - by just writing the usages in the top of the file.

```
using BrightIdeasSoftware;
```

Also, remove duplicated references in your project, so you will get rid of the errors.